How to use CASE with CONTAINS and Array Aggregation
I am trying to write a query using a CASE statement that is based off whether a value is in array, but I run into the catch 22 of not including the case statement in the GROUP BY and getting "must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause" or including it in the GROUP BY and getting "GROUP BY clause cannot contain aggregations, window functions or grouping operations" so I know I'm missing something. My query is:
Select
    title,
    owner,
    CASE
        WHEN CONTAINS(SET_AGG(team_id, 1234)) then project_name
        ELSE array_join(set_agg(project_name), CHR(10))
    END AS project_name
FROM actions
GROUP BY 1,2

Actions can belong to more than one team, but if I know it's part of a specific team, I want to use that project name, otherwise I just want to return all the project names. Some example date would be



title
owner
team_id
project_name




test1
owner1
1234
ProjectA


test2
owner1
1234
ProjectB


test2
owner1
6789
ProjectC


test3
owner2
4567
ProjectD


test3
owner2
6789
ProjectE



and the return should be:



title
owner
project_name




test1
owner1
ProjectA


test2
owner1
ProjectB


test3
owner2
ProjectD ProjectE



I tried grouping by just the first two columns and grouping by all three columns, and it errors both ways.

Is there a parenthesis missing here SET_AGG(team_id, ? All documenation I could find shows SET_AGG as an aggregation function taking one parameter.

around the case you need to add a aggregation function

Where did the result row (test2, owner2) come from? no such combination in your sample data.

@tinazmu Added the missing parenthesis and fixed owner2 to be owner1

@nbk what sort of aggregate function? I tried using MAX and got the error "Cannot nest aggregations inside aggregation 'max':"

You want to aggregate your rows in two different ways; a union would work 1st part for those in the known teams, and the second part for the remainder. Would you be interested in a solution like that?

I can see what you trying to do.
The issue is you are trying to use an aggregate function (SET_AGG) inside a CASE statement, which is not allowed. Additionally, you can't include the CASE statement in the GROUP BY clause because it's not a column or an aggregate function.
Here is a possible solution.
SELECT
    title,
    owner,
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM actions a2
            WHERE a2.team_id = 1234
            AND a2.title = actions.title
            AND a2.owner = actions.owner
        ) THEN  (SELECT array_join(ARRAY_AGG(project_name), CHR(10)) FROM actions a3 WHERE a3.title = actions.title AND a3.owner = actions.owner AND a3.team_id != 1234)
    ELSE array_join(ARRAY_AGG(project_name), CHR(10))
    END AS project_name
FROM actions
GROUP BY 1, 2


I replaced SET_AGG with ARRAY_AGG, which is an aggregate function that returns an array of values.
I moved the CASE statement outside the aggregate function.
I used EXISTS clause to check there at    least on row in the
actions table that matches the specific team ID    (1234).


Thanks for the response! When I modified my query to look like yours, I am still getting project_names for other team_ids when an action has the specific team_id I'm looking for. Using my sample date, I would still get a row for test2, owner2, ProjectC tied to team_id 6789 even though I only want the ProjectB tied to team_id 1234

I see your point, I made the changes in query, to achieve this, you can use a subquery to get the list of project_name values for each title and owner combination.
I am assuming that project_name is a column in the actions table. If that's not the case, please modify it as needed.
